# Say feature in Perl

Tags: perl

I Have a below Perl code

```
$fs_headerrecord_cut_casettenumber_pad_len = 2;
$fs_headerrecord_batch_casettenumber_start_pos = 21;
$fs_headerrecord_batch_casettenumber_data_len = 2;
$fs_header_record = 1;
$pad_length = 0;
my $dir = ".";
opendir(DIR, $dir) or die "Cannot open directory: $dir!\n";
my @files = readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);

open my $out, ">>output.txt" or die "Cannot open cutfile!\n";
foreach my $file (@files) {

    #next unless (-M $file <= 1 && $file =~ /^fs.*\.DTA$/i) ;
    if (-M $file <= 1 && $file =~ /^fs.*\.DTA$/i) {
        #print log_date() ."$file\n";
        print "$file\n";
        open my $fs_in, "<$file" or die "Cannot open $file!\n";
        while (<$fs_in>) {
            $recordlength = substr($_,220,1);
            if ($recordlength == $fs_header_record) {
                say $out ' ' x $pad_length, 'H', substr($_,0,1), say $out ' ' x $fs_headerrecord_cut_casettenumber_pad_len, substr($_, $fs_headerrecord_batch_casettenumber_start_pos, $fs_headerrecord_batch_casettenumber_data_len);
```

I want to write "H" before casettenumber. The output which i am getting is below

```
OUTPUT



14
H 1
  14
H 1
  14
H 1
  14
H 1
  14
H 1
  14
```

Expected Output

```
H 14
H 14
H 14
H 14
H 14
```

When i am printing "H" it is getting printed in a new line. Can anybody please tell me what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Don't use comma between prints (`say "hi", say "ho";`), but write them as separate statements, `say "hi"; say "ho";`. The prints are coming out in reversed order and you're getting an extra `1` printed, too.

Comment: if i am using ; like say $out ' ' x $pad_length, $write;        say $out ' ' x $fs_headerrecord_cut_casettenumber_pad_len, substr($_, $fs_headerrecord_batch_casettenumber_start_pos, $fs_hea
derrecord_batch_casettenumber_data_len);  Then 1 is not getting printed but "H" is on another line

Comment: I want like the expected output which i have shown above

Comment: Ignore the above comment. This is now resolved

Comment: `say "blah"` is the equivalent of `print "blah\n"` - in other words, it adds a new line to the end of whatever you're `say`-ing.

Answer (score 2):

You are using 2 says, so you will print 2 newlines.

See: print vs say:

https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html

https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html

Also, you are printing an extra "1" because you are printing the return value of the second say as a parameter to the first say.

Try replacing this:

```
say $out ' ' x $pad_length, 'H', substr($_,0,1), say $out ' ' x $fs_headerrecord_cut_casettenumber_pad_len, substr($_, $fs_headerrecord_batch_casettenumber_start_pos, $fs_headerrecord_batch_casettenumber_data_len);
```

with this:

```
print $out ' ' x $pad_length, 'H', substr($_,0,1);
say $out ' ' x $fs_headerrecord_cut_casettenumber_pad_len, substr($_, $fs_headerrecord_batch_casettenumber_start_pos, $fs_headerrecord_batch_casettenumber_data_len);
```

or send all data to the same say statement:

```
say $out 
    ' ' x $pad_length, 'H', 
    substr($_,0,1),
    $out ' ' x $fs_headerrecord_cut_casettenumber_pad_len, 
    substr($_, $fs_headerrecord_batch_casettenumber_start_pos, $fs_headerrecord_batch_casettenumber_data_len);
```